# CloudKit: CKQuery predicate IN array of recordChangeTag

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit

I'm trying to do a CKQuery with a predicate like:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat@"recordChangeTag IN %@", @[record.recordChangeTag]]
```

Description looks like:

```
recordChangeTag IN {"ijrz21fi"}
```

The CKQueryOperation errors with:

```
<CKError 0x7ff5cd3d2fc0: "Invalid Arguments" (12/1009); "Field '___etag' has a value type of NUMBER_INT64 and cannot be queried using filter value type STRING_LIST">
```

Anyone have a workaround for removing the quotes so it is not converted to a STRING_LIST when sent to the server? Or any other ideas to make it work?

Comment: Wrap the `NSString` in an `NSNumber`.

Comment: I tried a scanning it as base 32 unsigned long long but didn't work. What do you mean by wrap?

Answer (score -1):

`record.recordChangeTag` is a String. Because of that the NSPredicate will assume that you are querying a String and will put quotes around the value. You should convert it first to a number. Besides that, I don't think the field is a list so you can use = instead of IN.

If you were using Swift your code will look like:
NSPredicate(format: "recordChangeTag = %@", Int64(record.recordChangeTag!)!)

But then... why are you querying the recordChangeTag? Is that even possible? If so, then you will only get a result if the record is not changed since you got the changeTag. Couldn't you just query the recordID and test if the changeTag is not changed?

Comment: I'm using IN because I actually have an array of change tags, but it's the same error with equals. The reason I'm querying the change tag is I don't want to download the record again if I already have it and the change tag uniquely identifies a version of a record, however recordID and modificationDate also identifies a version but is more cumbersome to check for multiple.

Comment: If you do this to show/use new info in your app, then you could solve this with a subscription. Then a change will be pushed and you don't need to poll it at all. If it's because you are updating data and want to make sure it's not changed, then you should not do it at all. You should just execute an update. If it's changed it will fail and you will get the updated data in the error. Besides that your logic is wrong. It will only download what you already have and not the changed.

Comment: I removed the NOT IN to simplify the example. I don't want a subscription because there would be too many changes to push, updating when the app launches is all I need. And it's not for updating it's for getting changes.